# Why does Galera Cluster show port 0?

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am trying to set up my first Galera cluster with MariaDB 11.0.2 on an Arch-based system. I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Galera

## server.conf file

```
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2"
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
#
# Extra settings from AUR tutorial
#
wsrep_node_address='192.168.50.1'
wsrep_node_name='node1'
wsrep_cluster_name='my_galera_cluster'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
```

## Firewall config

Both servers have the following firewall configuration in case anything goes through:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
4567/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
4567/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
4567/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
4567/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

And I haven't forwarded any ports on my router.

## No explicitly specified ports

The first node was re-started alone, and then I added the second one to the config file. Here is the log after starting the first node alone:

```
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 2372.
 PC-1 sh[5395]: WSREP: Recovered position 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:74
 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.0.2-MariaDB source revision 0005f2f06c8e1aea4915887decad67885108a929 as process 5468
 0 [Note] WSREP: Loading provider /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so initial position: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:74
 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 26.4.14(rXXXX) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing allowlist service v1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing event service v1
 0 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using 64-bit x86 acceleration.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:-1, safe_to_bootstrap: 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache DEBUG: opened preamble:
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: Version: 2
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: UUID: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: Seqno: 1 - 74
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: Offset: 1280
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: Synced: 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: version: 2, UUID: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29, offset: 1280
 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...  0.0% (        0/134217752 bytes) complete.
 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...100.0% (134217752/134217752 bytes) complete.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: found gapless sequence 1-74
 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...  0.0% (    0/29176 bytes) complete.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: found 4/78 locked buffers
 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: free space: 134189224/134217728
 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...100.0% (29176/29176 bytes) complete.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 192.168.50.1; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; cert.optimistic_pa = yes; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.keep_plaintext_size = 128M; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = yes; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.fc_single_primary = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment =
 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
 0 [Note] WSREP: ####### Assign initial position for certification: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:74, protocol version: -1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
 0 [Note] WSREP: Connecting with bootstrap option: 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Setting GCS initial position to 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:74
 0 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
 0 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
 0 [Note] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
 0 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
 0 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
 0 [Note] WSREP: (3a073260-bfb3, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
 0 [Note] WSREP: (3a073260-bfb3, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: bootstrapping new group 'my_galera_cluster'
 0 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version upgrade 0 -> 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol upgrade 0 -> 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Node 3a073260-bfb3 state prim
 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,3a073260-bfb3,1) memb {
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         3a073260-bfb3,0
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: } joined {
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: } left {
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: } partitioned {
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: })
 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
 0 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://192.168.50.1:4567
 0 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr proto entry 0x7f51c8ea1dc0
 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
 0 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
 0 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'my_galera_cluster'
 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 3a0796b5-2bff-11ee-bfee-6a626f287cac
 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 3a0796b5-2bff-11ee-bfee-6a626f287cac
 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 3a0796b5-2bff-11ee-bfee-6a626f287cac from 0 (node1)
 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         version    = 6,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         component  = PRIMARY,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         conf_id    = 0,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         act_id     = 74,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         last_appl. = 74,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         protocols  = 2/10/4 (gcs/repl/appl),
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         vote policy= 0,
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         group UUID = 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
 0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing config service v1
 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
 0 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (75)
 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (node1) synced with group.
 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 75)
 0 [Note] WSREP: Deinitializing config service v1
 1 [Note] WSREP: Starting applier thread 1
 1 [Note] WSREP: ####### processing CC 75, local, ordered
 1 [Note] WSREP: Process first view: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29 my uuid: 3a073260-2bff-11ee-bfb3-de7316684bec
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server node1 connected to cluster at position 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:75 with ID 3a073260-2bff-11ee-bfb3-de7316684bec
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change disconnected -> connected
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 1 [Note] WSREP: ####### My UUID: 3a073260-2bff-11ee-bfb3-de7316684bec
 1 [Note] WSREP: Cert index reset to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 (proto: 10), state transfer needed: no
 2 [Note] WSREP: Starting rollbacker thread 2
 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
 1 [Note] WSREP: ####### Assign initial position for certification: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, protocol version: -1
 1 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 10 (5)
 1 [Note] WSREP: ####### Adjusting cert position: -1 -> 75
 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
 1 [Note] WSREP: ================================================
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: View:
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   id: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:75
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   status: primary
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   protocol_version: 4
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   capabilities: MULTI-MASTER, CERTIFICATION, PARALLEL_APPLYING, REPLAY, ISOLATION, PAUSE, CAUSAL_READ, INCREMENTAL_WS, UNORDERED, PREORDERED, STREAMING, NBO
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   final: no
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   own_index: 0
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:   members(1):
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]:         0: 3a073260-2bff-11ee-bfb3-de7316684bec, node1
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: =================================================
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change connected -> joiner
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change joiner -> initializing
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resetting space id's in the doublewrite buffer
 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 9944430; transaction id 8234
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230726 23:56:08
 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_init_schema_and_SR (nil)
 0 [Note] WSREP: Server initialized
 0 [Note] WSREP: Server status change initializing -> initialized
 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 1 [Note] WSREP: Bootstrapping a new cluster, setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
 5 [Note] WSREP: Recovered cluster id 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change initialized -> joined
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 0 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MariaDB server acts as a replica and has its hostname changed. Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=PC-1-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
 1 [Note] WSREP: Lowest cert index boundary for CC from group: 75
 1 [Note] WSREP: Min available from gcache for CC from group: 1
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server node1 synced with group
 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change joined -> synced
 1 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
 0 [Note] /usr/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
 PC-1 mariadbd[5468]: Version: '11.0.2-MariaDB'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Arch Linux
 PC-1 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 11.0.2 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 2372.
```

and when I run {SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';} I get following output:

```
| wsrep_incoming_addresses      | 192.168.50.1:0
```

This is strange, because I didn't specify the port and what I see in the tutorial is that it would go to port 3306 and if I read the MariaDB site https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-address/, it tells me that the default port would be 4567. I get port 0 as the output and my second node cannot start the process and connect to the cluster.

## Explicitly specifying the port

If I explicitly add port 4567 to the server.conf files, then the first node starts like this.

```
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3088.
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 sh[7561]: WSREP: Recovered position 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:77
0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.0.2-MariaDB source revision 0005f2f06c8e1aea4915887decad67885108a929 as process 7637
0 [Note] WSREP: Loading provider /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so initial position: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:77
0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 26.4.14(rXXXX) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing allowlist service v1
0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing event service v1
0 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using 64-bit x86 acceleration.
0 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:-1, safe_to_bootstrap: 1
0 [Note] WSREP: GCache DEBUG: opened preamble:
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: Version: 2
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: UUID: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: Seqno: 1 - 77
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: Offset: 1280
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: Synced: 1
0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: version: 2, UUID: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29, offset: 1280
0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...  0.0% (        0/134217752 bytes) complete.
0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...100.0% (134217752/134217752 bytes) complete.
0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: found gapless sequence 1-77
0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...  0.0% (    0/30184 bytes) complete.
0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: found 4/81 locked buffers
0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: free space: 134188216/134217728
0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...100.0% (30184/30184 bytes) complete.
0 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 192.168.50.1; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; cert.optimistic_pa = yes; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.keep_plaintext_size = 128M; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = yes; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.fc_single_primary = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment =
0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
0 [Note] WSREP: ####### Assign initial position for certification: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:77, protocol version: -1
0 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
0 [Note] WSREP: Connecting with bootstrap option: 1
0 [Note] WSREP: Setting GCS initial position to 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:77
0 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
0 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
0 [Note] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
0 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
0 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
0 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to resolve tcp:// 192.168.50.2:4567
0 [Note] WSREP: (a58d9b00-a234, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
0 [Note] WSREP: (a58d9b00-a234, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 1
0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: bootstrapping new group 'my_galera_cluster'
0 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version upgrade 0 -> 1
0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol upgrade 0 -> 1
0 [Note] WSREP: Node a58d9b00-a234 state prim
0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,a58d9b00-a234,1) memb {
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         a58d9b00-a234,0
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: } joined {
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: } left {
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: } partitioned {
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: })
0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
0 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://192.168.50.1:4567
0 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr proto entry 0x7f1c9bca1f00
0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
0 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
0 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'my_galera_cluster'
0 [Note] WSREP: Initializing config service v1
0 [Note] WSREP: Deinitializing config service v1
1 [Note] WSREP: Starting rollbacker thread 1
0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
0 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: a58e32b6-2c06-11ee-ab9d-02d8b136b251
0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: a58e32b6-2c06-11ee-ab9d-02d8b136b251
0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: a58e32b6-2c06-11ee-ab9d-02d8b136b251 from 0 (node1)
0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         version    = 6,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         component  = PRIMARY,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         conf_id    = 0,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         act_id     = 77,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         last_appl. = 77,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         protocols  = 2/10/4 (gcs/repl/appl),
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         vote policy= 0,
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         group UUID = 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
0 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (78)
0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (node1) synced with group.
0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 78)
2 [Note] WSREP: Starting applier thread 2
2 [Note] WSREP: ####### processing CC 78, local, ordered
2 [Note] WSREP: Process first view: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29 my uuid: a58d9b00-2c06-11ee-a234-268a7a230a30
2 [Note] WSREP: Server node1 connected to cluster at position 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:78 with ID a58d9b00-2c06-11ee-a234-268a7a230a30
2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change disconnected -> connected
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2 [Note] WSREP: ####### My UUID: a58d9b00-2c06-11ee-a234-268a7a230a30
2 [Note] WSREP: Cert index reset to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 (proto: 10), state transfer needed: no
0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2 [Note] WSREP: ####### Assign initial position for certification: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, protocol version: -1
2 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 10 (5)
2 [Note] WSREP: ####### Adjusting cert position: -1 -> 78
0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2 [Note] WSREP: ================================================
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: View:
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   id: 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29:78
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   status: primary
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   protocol_version: 4
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   capabilities: MULTI-MASTER, CERTIFICATION, PARALLEL_APPLYING, REPLAY, ISOLATION, PAUSE, CAUSAL_READ, INCREMENTAL_WS, UNORDERED, PREORDERED, STREAMING, NBO
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   final: no
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   own_index: 0
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:   members(1):
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]:         0: a58d9b00-2c06-11ee-a234-268a7a230a30, node1
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: =================================================
2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change connected -> joiner
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change joiner -> initializing
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
0 [Note] InnoDB: Resetting space id's in the doublewrite buffer
0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 9948213; transaction id 8259
0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230727  0:49:15
0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_init_schema_and_SR (nil)
0 [Note] WSREP: Server initialized
0 [Note] WSREP: Server status change initializing -> initialized
0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2 [Note] WSREP: Bootstrapping a new cluster, setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
5 [Note] WSREP: Recovered cluster id 232842bc-2a5b-11ee-9942-1224fb5b0d29
2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change initialized -> joined
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
0 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MariaDB server acts as a replica and has its hostname changed. Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=PC-1-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2 [Note] WSREP: Lowest cert index boundary for CC from group: 78
2 [Note] WSREP: Min available from gcache for CC from group: 1
2 [Note] WSREP: Server node1 synced with group
2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change joined -> synced
2 [Note] WSREP: Synchronized with group, ready for connections
2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
0 [Note] /usr/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 mariadbd[7637]: Version: '11.0.2-MariaDB'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Arch Linux
lip 27 00:49:15 PC-1 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 11.0.2 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished successfully.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3088.
```

Where this line jumps out as problematic.

```
0 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to resolve tcp:// 192.168.50.2:4567
```

Another thing that changes when explicitely specifying the ports is that systemctl cannot start the mariadb.service and when I abort the process. I have no log lines in journalctl. Everything else is the same.

### Maybe a bug?

I see here, that this is maybe a bug that happened in older versions of MariaDB and hasn't yet been fixed for the newest release. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28868

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have reported it to MariaDB Jira.